# SQL select query get Date in different language the month

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In select query file i have fixed the 12 month other language(Maltis).

```
$jan='ޖެނުއަރީ';
$feb='ފެބްރުއަރީ';
$mar='މާޗް';
$apr='އޭޕްރީލް';
$mai='މެއި';
$jun='ޖޫން';
$jul='ޖުލައި';
$aug='އޯގަސްޓު';
$sep='ސެޕްޓެމްބަރ';
$oct='އޮކްޓޯބަރ';
$nov='ނޮވެންބަރ';
$dec='ޑިސެންބަރ';
```

And in PDO select query i wrote

```
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

$sql = "SELECT id, heading, DATE_FORMAT(`mytable`.`date`,  CONCAT( ' %Y ', ELT( MONTH('2004-04-10'), '$jan','$feb','$mar','$apr','$mai','$jun','$jul','$aug','$sep','$okt','$nov','$dec'),' %d')) AS date FROM mytable WHERE publish = 1 AND type='$article_category' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,30";
```

**The problem is it show only April** because  i put in select query `ELT( MONTH('2004-04-10'),` .

what can i do??

Comment: can you provide table structure please?

Comment: table structure is
 id (int(6)), heading(varchar (50) ),date(datetime), publish (tinyint(1))